# Using GoDaddy domain with AWS hosting and GSuite Gmail, nothing working

Tags: amazon-web-services, godaddy, google-workspace

I am using domain on GoDaddy, and Hosting is setup on AWS. The site name is adverscribe.com. I have added the AWS nameservers in GoDaddy and its already around 48 hours. But even then my website is not reachable.Also, my GSuite gmail is not working whereas I have added the MX Records on AWS. Do I need to update my GoDaddy MX records as well?